# Proper way to handle nested subscriptions in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-observables

I'm trying to create pagination for an angular 2 web app with query parameters and observables.  I've gotten things to work with the code below, but I have a feeling that nesting the subscriptions isn't a good idea.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
  blogs:any;
  page = 0;
  sub;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
           this.page = +params['page'] || 0;
           this.requestService.getData('posts', '..query string...')
       .subscribe(data => this.blogs = data.data);
     });
  }
  nextPage() {
      this.router.navigate(['./'], { queryParams: { page: this.page + 1 }, relativeTo: this.route }   );
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.switchMap` to chain observable.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.queryParams
  .switchMap(params => {
       this.page = +params['page'] || 0;
       return this.requestService.getData('posts', '..query string...')
  })
  .subscribe(data => this.blogs = data.data);
}
```